# Weird rendering issue using MVC helpers and bootstrap

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Does MVC do something weird with spacing? This is the issue:
[image: Render issues]

And this is the code:

[image: Code]

The only difference between the code is that the href is not `#`. The links that have a href are generated using `Html.ActionLink` while the others are hand coded.

Switching cells and such does not have an impact. The links with href are always smushed together, while the links that link to "#" are nicely spaced.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: any chance you could add the html and css as text?

Comment: Compare the css of both anchor tag by pressing f12 in chrome browser. I think there must be different styles for anchor tag for first td and for other tds.

Comment: I think I found the error, and it's googles devtools that are tricking me while trying to debug. If the links are one per line they get spacing, however the helper just smashes them together. So chrome counts a linebreak as one whitespace.

Comment: Confirmed this by hacking in a linebreak in the loop (the buttons are rendered in a foreach). Stuffed a ``String.Format("\n")`` in there and the rendered spacing is correct...